# Support Action bar menu not getting displayed

Tags: android, exception, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement ActionBar support Library with v7 Appcompact . I extend my Activity class with ActionBarActivity.

I'm using `@style/Theme.AppCompat` as theme.

Below is my main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    System.out.println("********onCreateOptionsMenu*************");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    System.out.println("********onOptionsItemSelected*************");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
           Toast.makeText(this, "Search clicked!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My menu xml file is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.android.wit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >   
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        com.android.wit:showAsAction="always"  />    
 </menu>
```

With the above code when I run my application, the actionbar with menu is not getting displayed and when I click on the device menu button, I'm getting the following runtime exception and the app crashes.

```
10-04 14:49:03.356: I/InputDispatcher(2936): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x0
10-04 14:49:03.361: I/System.out(12059): ********onCreateOptionsMenu*************
10-04 14:49:03.361: D/AndroidRuntime(12059): Shutting down VM
10-04 14:49:03.361: W/dalvikvm(12059): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ab7930)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:274)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:89)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getMenuInflater(ActionBarActivity.java:71)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.wit.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:42)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2550)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:224)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:141)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:280)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:876)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1570)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2083)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4125)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3173)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-04 14:49:03.366: E/AndroidRuntime(12059):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 14:49:03.396: E/Watchdog(2936): !@Sync 121
10-04 14:49:03.426: W/ContextImpl(2936): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1337 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked:1342 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked:5865 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked:5779 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked:9428 
10-04 14:49:03.431: D/CrashAnrDetector(2936): processName: com.android.wit
10-04 14:49:03.431: D/CrashAnrDetector(2936): broadcastEvent : com.android.wit data_app_crash
```

If anybody has come across the same situation, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem. In my case nothing crashed. it just look like a spinner instead of search bar in android 4.0 and will shown in setting in android 2.3.
Adding "mine:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"" in MENU xml solved this for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mine="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >   
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        mine:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        mine:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"  />    
</menu>
```

that in your case "mine" should be changed with "com.android.wit", anything instead of default "android" namespace

Also check this one: [Android Support Library ActionBar not Working in 2.3 Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873648/android-support-library-actionbar-not-working-in-2-3-device)